# My name is simple, nothing tricky here

Tags: riddle, wordplay, history

- My nationality is English.
- I am born at 1859
- I am bald, but I've never been bothered by it.
- I have always been on the round side, and people don't hesitate to point that out.
- Throughout my years I've always been pretty loud.
- My name is simple, nothing tricky here.

What is my name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your name

> Ben?

> I just looked at [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1859) and saw that **July 11 – The chimes of Big Ben ring for the first time in London.**
>
>  The other sentences seem to match, too.
>
>
>  **My nationality is English.** The Big Ben is located in London.
>
>  **I am born at 1859.** Its construction completed in 1859.
>
>  **I am bald, but I've never been bothered by it.** As a bell, it has no hair.
>
>  **I have always been on the round side, and people don't hesitate to point that out.** People say *Big* Ben, *big* can mean one is on the round side.
>
>  **Throughout my years I've always been pretty loud.** Being a great bell, it is quite loud.
>
>  **My name is simple, nothing tricky here.** The nickname "Ben" is just so simple.

Comment: Hi, this is correct! Can you provide a more detailed answer, like a description for each line?

Comment: I added some explanations. Not sure whether I got all the details.

Answer (score -4):

Maybe

> some kind of English "chubby"(always been on the round side) hairless(bald, but never been bothered about it) dog breed which was first introduced in 1859? Can't seem to find a specific dog breed which fits the description exactly, though.

Comment: Just curious, if you couldn't find an answer that fit why did you make an answer post?